# Repeat codeline in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat

How can I repeat a code-line in R?

I have created a function called 'func1' and I want ‘data’ to run though ‘func1’ 10 times after another

This is what I have now:

```
data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data)
data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data);data<-func1(data)
```

This is what I would like to have:

solution

```
data<-func1(data,times=10)
```

Thanks in advance

Jannik

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do this,

```
for(i in 1:10) {
     data <- func1(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a higher-order function which, given a function, `f`, a seed value, `s`, and an integer `n`, computes

```
f(f(f( ....(s))...)
```

(with `n` function evalutions):

```
iterate <- function(f,s,n){
  if(n == 0){
    s
  }
  else{
    f(iterate(f,s,n-1))
  }
}
```

Then you seem to want `data <- iterate(func1,data,10)`

You can also write `iterate` using a loop (in a way which is similar to the excellent answer of @JamesElderfield ) but the recursive approach given above is fairly common in the functional programming paradigm (which is one of R's native paradigms).